# OneDrive Share Not Shared

Tags: onedrive, cloud-storage

**The Question**: How can I set up a folder or folder-tree on OneDrive on the desktop so it shares contents placed in the folder with additional users?

**Additional Details**: I have a few users that have been having trouble with their OneDrive shares since we rolled them up to Windows 10. They can access their OneDrives without any issue, but some of the folders they have shared with others are only saving the files locally and not in the cloud.

For example the folder Legal will have a [Green Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtDuR.png) instead of the [Blue Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMgLW.png). I tried sharing the folders via the "share" option with the other users but now they just have the Green Check with a [Little Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFyW3.png) out to the side but no documents placed in that folder of OneDrive will actually share. It'll only share what was in there at the moment of sharing and not continually syncing the OneDrive across all users who have access.

**I have tried**:

- Signing them out, deleting the cache, and signing back in.
- Sharing the drive with the built in feature.
- Sharing the file through the Online version of OneDrive (this worked, but we want to do it locally rather than through OWA)

Comment: One point of clarification is that as of Windows 10, OneDrive now doesn't sync all files to your computer automatically - it downloads them on demand when you open them. The Blue Cloud means the file is in your OneDrive but not yet downloaded, whereas the Green Check means the file is actually downloaded to your PC. You can customize which folders/files have a local copy on your PC by right-clicking on the file/folder and clicking "Always keep on this device".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why they're seeing a static list of the files available when you first shared, but in order to get the folder to show up in their OneDrive so it syncs to their PC, the recipients of the share need to go to https://onedrive.live.com --> click on "Shared" --> right click on the folder they want to sync to their OneDrive and click "Add to my OneDrive".

Comment: No dice, when one user puts a file into the shared folder it doesn't place it in the folder of the other user. So they are having to manually share the files via USB just to gain access to them quickly.